# AutoCompleteTextField list does not always scroll to top?

Tags: autocomplete, codenameone

The AutoCompleteTextField seems to work exactly as intended until I start backspacing in the TextField.  I am not sure what the difference is, but if I type in something like "123 M" then I get values that start with "123 M".  If I backspace and delete the M leaving "123 " in the field, the list changes, but it does not scroll to the top of the list.

I should note that everything works fine on the simulator and that I am experiencing this behavior when running a debug build on my iPhone.

EDIT: So this does not only seem to happen when backspacing.  This image shows the results I have when typing in an address key by key.  In any of the pictures where the list isn't viewable or is clipped, I am able to drag down on the list to get it to then display properly.  I have not tried this on an Android device.

EDIT2:

```
public class CodenameOneTest {

  private Form current;
  private Resources theme;
  private WaitingClass w;
  private String[] properties = {"1 MAIN STREET", "123 E MAIN STREET", "12 EASTER ROAD", "24 MAIN STREET"};

  public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

    // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
  }

  public void start() {
    if(current != null) {
      current.show();
      return;
    }
    Form form = new Form("AutoCompleteTextField");
    form.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    final DefaultListModel<String> options = new DefaultListModel<>();
    AutoCompleteTextField ac = new AutoCompleteTextField(options) {
      protected boolean filter(String text) {
        if(text.length() == 0) {
          options.removeAll();
          return false;
        }

        String[] l = searchLocations(text);
        if(l == null || l.length == 0) {
          return false;
        }

        options.removeAll();
        for(String s : l) {
          options.addItem(s);
        }
        return true;
      };
    };
    Container container = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
    container.setScrollableY(true); // If you comment this out then the field works fine
    container.add(ac);

    form.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, container);
    form.show();
  }

  String[] searchLocations(String text) {
    try {
      if(text.length() > 0) {
        if(w != null) {
          w.actionPerformed(null);
        }
        w = new WaitingClass();
        String[] properties = getProperties(text);
        if(Display.getInstance().isEdt()) {
          Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(w);
        }
        else {
          w.run();
        }
        return properties;
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(e);
    }
    return null;
  }

  private String[] getProperties(String text) {
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> propertyList = Arrays.asList(properties);
    for(String property : propertyList) {
      if(property.startsWith(text)) {
        returnList.add(property);
      }
    }
    w.actionPerformed(null);
    return returnList.toArray(new String[returnList.size()]);
  }

  class WaitingClass implements Runnable, ActionListener<ActionEvent> {
    private boolean finishedWaiting;

    public void run() {
      while(!finishedWaiting) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(30);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      finishedWaiting = true;
      return;
    }
  }

  public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    if(current instanceof Dialog) {
      ((Dialog)current).dispose();
      current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    }
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work correctly on Android/other devices? Can you provide some screenshots to give us a sense of how this looks?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I added a screenshot!

Comment: I asked Steve to try and reproduce this and we were unable to. Can you post a test case that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I am thinking the issue has something to do with how I am searching the locations.  Unlike the Dynamic AutoComplete example, I am sending a message to a server through a WebSocket and then blocking until a return message is received containing the locations.  I will try my best to throw a test case together.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog While producing the test case it seems like I was able to narrow down what causes the behavior.  When I have the field in a container where I've called `container.setScrollableY(true);` then the issue seems to occur.  If I do not call `setScrollableY(true);` on the container then the field works perfectly.  If I have the field directly on a Form with no other containers in between, then it works regardless of setting the scrollableY flag.

Comment: Is it possible you have a nested scrollable in the hierarchy? What is the layout of the form itself?

Comment: I stripped things all the way down to a Form with a BorderLayout and then a Container with BoxLayout Y-Axis at the Center.  At that point the issue occurs if I setScrollableY to true and works fine if I don't.  Problem is I need the container to be scrollable due to other fields that don't fit otherwise.

Comment: Can you create a test case that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Just included the test case.  Thanks

Comment: Can you point out how your example is different from https://www.codenameone.com/blog/dynamic-autocomplete.html the only major difference I saw here was an extra `removeAll` but I might have missed something? Does our sample reproduce the issue for you?

Comment: The biggest difference is setting scrollableY to true on the AutoCompleteTextField's parent container.  However, if you add the field to a form directly without using any other containers and setting scrollableY to true then it works fine.  So it is reproducible when you have a Form > Container (with scrollableY set to true) > AutoCompleteTextField.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce that and couldn't. Were you able to reproduce it in the simulator in those conditions or only on iOS? Does it happen on Android?

Comment: Only on iOS.  I still have not gotten my hands on an Android to test it with yet.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code on an iPhone 4s:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
   Form hi = new Form("AutoComplete", new BorderLayout());
   if(apiKey == null) {
       hi.add(new SpanLabel("This demo requires a valid google API key to be set in the constant apiKey, "
               + "you can get this key for the webservice (not the native key) by following the instructions here: "
               + "https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key"));
       hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("Get Key", null, e -> Display.getInstance().execute("https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key"));
       hi.show();
       return;
   }
    Container box = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    box.setScrollableY(true);
   for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 30 ; iter++) {
        box.add(createAutoComplete());
   }
   hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, box);
    hi.show();
}

private AutoCompleteTextField createAutoComplete() {
    final DefaultListModel<String> options = new DefaultListModel<>();
    AutoCompleteTextField ac = new AutoCompleteTextField(options) {
        @Override
        protected boolean filter(String text) {
            if(text.length() == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            String[] l = searchLocations(text);
            if(l == null || l.length == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            options.removeAll();
            for(String s : l) {
                options.addItem(s);
            }
            return true;
        }

    };
    ac.setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(5);
    return ac;
}

String[] searchLocations(String text) {        
    try {
        if(text.length() > 0) {
            ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
            r.setPost(false);
            r.setUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json");
            r.addArgument("key", apiKey);
            r.addArgument("input", text);
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
            Map<String,Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
            String[] res = Result.fromContent(result).getAsStringArray("//description");
            return res;
        }
    } catch(Exception err) {
        Log.e(err);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I was able to create this issue [image] but not the issue you describe.